# C# - Type conversion issue when calling base class method from derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting, type-conversion

I need to retrieve an extended attribute from Active Directory, for
which there is a private method in the `ComputerPrincipal` class. I
understand I can only access the private method through a derived
class, so I've derived a class `ComputerPrincipalEx` from the base
class. I've then created (defined?) a method in the derived class
which calls the private method in the base class. This part seems OK.

The problem comes when I try to use a (public) method of the base
class to assign a value to a variable with the type of the derived
class. Here's the code, then I'll try to explain more:

The derived class:

```
public class ComputerPrincipalEx : ComputerPrincipal
{
    public ComputerPrincipalEx(PrincipalContext context) : base(context) { }

    public ComputerPrincipalEx(PrincipalContext context, string samAccountName, string password, bool enabled) : base(context, samAccountName, password, enabled) { }

    public string ExtensionGet(string extendedattribute)
    {
        return (string) base.ExtensionGet(extendedattribute)[0];
    }

}
```

The problem code, which itself is a method of another class I've created:

> ```
> public string GetExtendedAttribute(string attributeName)
>     {
>         PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
>         ComputerPrincipalEx cp = new ComputerPrincipalEx(ctx);
>         cp = ComputerPrincipalEx.FindByIdentity(ctx, Name);
>         return cp.ExtensionGet(attributeName);
>     }
> ```

`ExtensionGet` is the private method of the base class that I need to
expose, and I think I have this correct because once I create an
object of type `ComputerPrincipalEx`, I can access `ExtensionGet`, which
is otherwise inaccessible.

The problem is the type conversion in this line:
    cp = ComputerPrincipalEx.FindByIdentity(ctx, Name);

`cp` is defined as `ComputerPrincipalEx;`
`ComputerPrincipalEx.FindByIdentity` references the base
`ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity` method, and returns a
`ComputerPrincipal`. The compiler balks about an implicit conversion
between types. Casting `ComputerPrincipal` to `ComputerPrincipalEx`
satisfies the compiler but the app crashes at runtime because it can't
perform the conversion.

Now, I pretty much understand all of that, but I'm assuming there has
to be some way to call a method from the base class and return valid
data to an object of the derived class' type, and that's what I'm
hoping to find out how to do.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but does `PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain); ComputerPrincipalEx cp = (ComputerPrincipalEx)ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, Name); return cp.ExtensionGet(attributeName);` work? By the way, in the first two statements the first word can be replaced by `var` if one prefers.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - The explicit cast satisfies the compiler but crashes at runtime because the app cannot convert from `ComputerPrincipal` to `ComputerPrincipalEx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out based on information I found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/118122/How-to-use-AD-Attributes-not-represented-in-UserPr) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23504921/problems-with-extending-s-ds-am-userprincipal-class).

In the derived `ComputerPrincipalEx` class, I needed to hide the base class' `FindByIdentity` method and redefine it to call `FindByIdentityWithType`. This let me cast the return type to be `ComputerPrincipalEx` and thus access the `ExtensionGet` method. (Hopefully I'm explaining that properly; this is still very new to me.)

For this to work however, the below lines needed to be added as well. Otherwise the compiler threw an error that `ComputerPrincipalEx` was not a valid object type to search with.

```
[DirectoryObjectClass("computer")]
[DirectoryRdnPrefix("CN")]
```

Here's the relevant excerpt from the `ComputerPrincipalEx` class: (Yes, I know the try/catch block needs some work.)

```
[DirectoryObjectClass("computer")]
[DirectoryRdnPrefix("CN")]

public class ComputerPrincipalEx : ComputerPrincipal
{
    public ComputerPrincipalEx(PrincipalContext context) : base(context) { }

    public ComputerPrincipalEx(PrincipalContext context, string samAccountName, string password, bool enabled) : base(context, samAccountName, password, enabled) { }

    new public string ExtensionGet(string extendedattribute)
    {
        try
        {
            if (base.ExtensionGet(extendedattribute).Length != 1)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                return (string)base.ExtensionGet(extendedattribute)[0];
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // This should be broken down to individual exceptions
            string message = string.Format("Exception occurred while retrieving extended attribute {0}. \r\nThe following error occurred:\r\n {1}", extendedattribute, ex);
            MessageBox.Show(message);
            Application.Exit();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static new ComputerPrincipalEx FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext ctx, string identityValue)
    {
        return (ComputerPrincipalEx)FindByIdentityWithType(ctx, typeof(ComputerPrincipalEx), identityValue);
    }
}
```

And the revised `GetExtendedAttribute` call:

```
    public string GetExtendedAttribute(string attributeName)
    {
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain); 
        var cp = ComputerPrincipalEx.FindByIdentity(ctx, Name); 
        return cp.ExtensionGet(attributeName);

    }
```

Thanks all for the help. Hopefully this helps someone else who runs into the same problem.

Comment: Sir, you are my hero. I have been trying to figure this exact same issue out for 8 hours now.

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
public string GetExtendedAttribute(string attributeName)
    {
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        var cp = ComputerPrincipalEx.FindByIdentity(ctx, Name);
        return cp.ExtensionGet(attributeName);
    }
```

Comment: When I make that change, "cp" becomes type ComputerPrincipal, and thus cp.ExtensionGet is again inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

In my impression, you need a constructor (or static method) in ComputerPrincipalEx which creates it from an instance of the base class.